Capybara-email save and open specific email in ActionMailer::Base.deliveries
I have an old project I'm updating soon, which currently uses Capybara ~> 3.6 and Capybara-email.
There's two emails that coincidentally fire off to the same email in a particular test, and I would like to look at both, but open_email('asdf@qwer.com') only opens the last email when current_email.save_and_open
Any way to set ActionMailer::Base.deliveries[2]  in open_email, or otherwise somehow look at both?

Based on the Source Code open_email, which is an alias for first_email_sent_to (a very misleading name), just pulls the last email sent to a given email address and assigns it to current_email:
def first_email_sent_to(recipient)
  self.current_email = emails_sent_to(recipient).last
end
alias :open_email :first_email_sent_to

This method utilizes emails_sent_to so we can leverage that method to get the last 2 emails sent to that address.
emails_sent_to('asdf@qwer.com').last(2) 

Since save_and_open just opens a browser to view the email we should be able to achieve your desired functionality using:
emails_sent_to('asdf@qwer.com').last(2).each(&:save_and_open)

Since emails_sent_to is simply an Array of Capybara::Node::Email objects, if you need to target something other than the last 2 you can filter them in any way you see fit:
target_emails = emails_sent_to('asdf@qwer.com').select do |email|
  # filter your emails here
  email.subject =~ /target description/i
end  


whoa, dissecting a gem past its documentation, I will check this in a bit, much appreciated
